# How to get an index for an element in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

If I have:

```
a = np.array(['A','B','C','D'])
```

How do I get the index for the letter 'C'?

Comment: Note that this is a pretty inefficient way to interact with NumPy arrays. (It's pretty bad for regular Python lists, too.) Look for better ways to solve your problem before trying to search arrays like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` will find all the positions:

```
> np.where(a == 'C')[0][0]
2
```